# Rails Polymer not formatting CSS and Polymer elements correctly until I refresh the page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, polymer

My polymer elements (such as paper-input) don't load their CSS correctly whenever I first load a page. For example: [image: Before reloading]

I have to refresh the page everytime for it to display correctly. This is how the page is supposed to look like:
[image: After reloading]

This is the code for the page:

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {id: "form"}) do |f| %>
    <paper-input-container alwaysFloatLabel="false">
      <label>Email</label>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, 'is':'iron-input' %>
    </paper-input-container>

    <paper-input-container alwaysFloatLabel="false">
      <label>Password</label>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", 'is':'iron-input' %>
    </paper-input-container>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <paper-checkbox id="rememberme"></paper-checkbox>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me, id: "rememberme", style: "display: none;" %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    <% end -%>
    <br><br>
    <paper-button id="submit">Log in</paper-button>
  <% end %>

  <hr>
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Is there a way for it to load the CSS correctly on the first time? Or is this issue only present on development?

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console? Does resizing the browser window a bit also fix the layout?

Comment: I don't get an error message in the console. It seems like the turbolinks gem is causing the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the turbolinks gem is causing these issues. Removing turbolinks resolves the issue.

Comment: Any solution to Polymer and Turbolinks together?